# Can we trace user space code in Android environment?

Tags: android, debugging, arm, adb, embedded-linux

For Linux kernel ETM tracing, we use vmlinux, which files will be needed for userspace ETM trace?

Tried ETM tracing using vmlinux file. But not sure on which elf files to use for user space tracing like applications on phone etc.